# Is it possible to override MVC View Scaffolding on a property basis?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, t4, scaffolding

Is it possible that based on attributes on a property, instead of

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyName)
</div>
```

the following gets scaffolded

```
   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field-tall">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PropertyName, new { @rows = 5, @cols = 40 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyName)
    </div>
```

**without** rewriting, replacing, or copying into a new TT and then extending the mvc scaffolding templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without rewriting, replacing, or
>   copying into a new TT and then
>   extending the mvc scaffolding
>   templates?

No.

If you want to write your own mvc scaffolding templates, [I would read this post which will cover how you can override the T4 templates.](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/).